# atob in an interface of Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to solve a token storage issue, which on my view might be done through interfaces. My current code for login is the following:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface User {
  success: {
    id: number;
    role: string;
    accessToken: string;
    refreshToken: string;
    lifetime: {
      epoch: number;
      timeZone: number;
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})

export class LoginComponent {
  constructor( private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient ) { }

  loginInfo = this.fb.group({
    email: [''],
    password: ['']
  })

  onSubmit() {
    this.http.post<User>('', this.loginInfo.value)
      .subscribe(x => localStorage.setItem("currentUser",JSON.stringify(x)))
  };
}
```

The only problem is that refreshToken and accessToken come into Base64, which as far as I know is solved only with the atob() function. Is it possible to preliminarily solve it in the interface?

I understand that the following code does not work, but it is just to make the objective clearer:

```
interface User {
  success: {
    id: number;
    role: string;
    accessToken: atob(string);
    refreshToken: atob(string);
    lifetime: {
      epoch: number;
      timeZone: number;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Base64 is just a string, so simply type it as that. There is no way to define a regex on that string - apart from guards which will most likely not be worth it in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change the interface to class and use a getter to solve the base64 token, for example:

```
class UserSuccess {
  id: number;
  role: string;

  get accessToken(): string {
    return atob(this._accessToken);
  }
  set accessToken(value: string) {
    this._accessToken = value;
  }
  private _accessToken?: string;

  get refreshToken(): string {
    return atob(this._refreshToken);
  }
  set refreshToken(value: string) {
    this._refreshToken = value;
  }
  private _refreshToken?: string;

  lifetime: {
    epoch: number;
    timeZone: number;
  }
}

class User {
  success: UserSuccess;
}
```

Directly on the interface is not possible. Hope this helps.